# SQL Server: Display Users where a value follows another value in a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of users and their responses to a campaign:

```
user     campaign_id     date                response
John     5               2022/02/01 16:44    positive
Wendy    4               2022/02/01 16:00    negative
Wendy    5               2022/01/20 12:40    negative
John     16              2022/01/20 12:15    negative
Bob      16              2022/01/20 12:10    negative
Bob      5               2022/01/20 10:00    positive
John     10              2022/01/10 15:00    positive
Bob      2               2022/01/05 12:00    negative
Max      10              2022/01/05 11:45    positive
```

I'm attempting to write a query to just display users where we've received a negative response and then directly followed by a positive one (campaign_id doesn't matter).

My desired outcome

```
user     campaign_id     date                response
John     5               2022/02/01 16:44    positive
John     16              2022/01/20 12:15    negative
Bob      5               2022/01/20 10:00    positive
Bob      2               2022/01/05 12:00    negative
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: something on the lines of this: SELECT a.user, a.campaign_id, a.[date], a.response
    FROM db.dbo.user_response a 
    LEFT JOIN user_response b ON a.user = b.user AND b.response = 'negative'
    LEFT JOIN user_response c ON a.user = c.user AND c.response = 'positive'
    WHERE c.response > b.response
    GROUP BY a.user, a.campaign_id, a.[date], a.response
    ORDER BY a.user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rank() to the group and order your users, considering `testusers` is your table name.

```
;With OrderedUsers as
(
    SELECT *
    , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [user] order by date) Attempt
    FROM testusers
)
SELECT F.* 
FROM OrderedUsers F
INNER JOIN OrderedUsers S
ON F.[user] = S.[user] 
  AND S.Attempt = F.Attempt +1
  AND S.response = 'positive'  
where F.response = 'negative'

UNION 
SELECT S.* 
FROM OrderedUsers F
INNER JOIN OrderedUsers S
ON F.[user] = S.[user] 
  AND S.Attempt = F.Attempt +1
  AND S.response = 'positive'  
where F.response = 'negative'
```